# Android: Text formatting in paragraphs

Tags: android, android-webview, android-sqlite

I have text which is in xml and its a long text divided into several paragraphs. How shall I store this text in db and then retrieve it so that I get the text in the paragraphs form?

Comment: the question is not clear at all. Give more details on how your input looks like and what output you would like to have. Please check how to ask a question here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
"Heading\n\n\tThis is the first paragraph and you can see the second paragraph below.\n\n\tThis is the second"
```

Store like this. Use \n\n\t before starting each paragraph. \n is for new line and \t for tab.